# Design pattern for a large nested switch statements

Tags: oop, design-patterns, polymorphism, switch-statement

I've searched for a number of articles on refactoring a large `switch` statement.

But they don't do what I want to do. The problem **I'm going to** to run in to is having a gigantic switch statement which calls a different method depending on two different values, lets say a `type` and a `code`.

Currently, I would handle the situation like this:

```
switch (type)
{
    case Types.Type1:
        handleType1(code);
        break;

    case Types.Type2:
        handleType2(code);
        break;
}

void handleTypeN(code)
{
    switch (code)
    {
       ...
    }
}
```

Maybe something which combines the factory and command pattern would help me out? I must be missing something obvious.

How would you refactor this code?

---

I might need to get a little more specific as to what scenario I'm facing.

I'm receiving packets from a server. A packet contains a type and a code and some specific information.

As soon as data arrives I retrieve the `type` and the `code` of the packet and it goes in to the `switch` statement for the `type`, after figuring out the `type` a specific method is called to perform a switch on the `code` of the packet.

The method that handles the code now decodes the packet further and the process is done.

```
+----------+                +----------+
|          |     Packet     |          |
|  Server  | -------------> |  Client  |
|          |                |          |
+----------+                +----------+
                                  |
                                  |
         (Switch on the type of the packet and call a specific method)
                                  |
                                  |
         (Switch on the code of the packet and call a specific method)
                                  |
                                  |
                    (Respond to the server or not)
```

Comment: What's wrong with good old [polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science))? Are you working in an object-oriented language?

Comment: Can you be anymore specific as to what scenario this `switch` statement is being applied to?

Comment: @Cody It's not specific to actionscript, I'll be building the same system in C# and Java.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it depends what kind of code improvement you're trying to do.

If you have the luxury of actually making big design changes, then I'd suggest polymorphism:

Create an abstract Packet class.
Create a class for each packet type.
Create a factory method, that receives a raw server packet, and creates the right packet class object.
Each packet class type will have its own implementation of the job it needs to do.

If you don't have the luxury of doing large design changes (which is often the case):

- If you want to improve readability :

Keep the switch, each switch case will call a properly named function that will do what it needs to.

- If you want to increase performance:

Create a matrix, that for each cell [T,C] will hold a reference to a function that will handle a Packet with Type T and Code C.
The matrix should be initiated once (hard-coded, no way around that) at startup of program or class.
This will give you better performance than a long switch block (direct access to code, no logical comparisons)

Comment: +1 I've got the luxury :). I already got a factory that creates packets as well, but to create a packet from bytes I would still have to have a large switch statement inside of my factory and then delegate the packet to the right action!

Comment: But in this case you wouldn't need an array. You could have an enum which its values have the exact names of the Packet classes. Then just initiate the objects with the class names.

Comment: Anyway, point is that you can replace a large switch block with an array or matrix. Using proper OOP design for the packets will make it a bit more understandable, and will divide the logic better. Although you might get a slight overhead of creating the objects.

Comment: I've moved my code around a little bit and have now got a factory which creates packets from the raw data and a factory which creates a 'command' object to execute. The factories still have a switch statement but at least my functions have now been split up in to objects. I might put a hashtable in the factories like you suggested :).

Comment: You could use an enum and save yourself the need for the hashtable. if you use the exact class names for the enumerables you could use the enum's .ToString() method to get the name.

Comment: @Kevin, even if you cannot get rid of the switch statement as you said, it's always better to have it encapsulated inside, say, a factory method and work polimorphically. See ya!

Answer (score 5):

2 pattern comes in mind : command and visitor : 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern

```
Abstract Class Command {

 executeSomething();

}
Class typeN extends command {

   executeSomething() {
    //...
   }
}

Class typeM extends command {

   executeSomething() {
    //...
   }
}

replace your switch by :
//my old switch
class commandManager {

processCommand() {
for listOf command in a command buffer
{ 
 onCommand(listOfcommand.command)
}
}
 onCommandPoped(command type) {
  type.executeSomething()
 }

}

you can pass parameters to executeSomething, and you can pass another command


the client code : 

{
 commandN = new CommandN()
 commandManager.postCommand( commandN)
}
```

After reading your packet server use case, I think you can use a variant of strategy pattern
http://www.oodesign.com/strategy-pattern.html
where you choose the strategy to call when the packet arrive
you can build this with a factory.

but you will not kill your switch case

Keep in mind, that a server can serve many client. If it's maybe your switch cases are faster than object instanciation.

Comment: +1 if you do some proper formatting of your code, it is hard to read currently.

Comment: And some syntax highlight perhaps: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting ;)

Comment: +1 I was thinking about implementing the command pattern and factory, I'm just not sure how to yet.

Comment: Upvote for reading my mind - at least on the Strategy pattern part!  :)  Whenever you have multiple algorithms/techniques/approaches to accomplish a goal, and want to make a runtime decision of which technique to use, consider using the Strategy pattern.  I usually pair it up with the FactoryMethod pattern:  basically, call the FactoryMethod, passing whatever data is necessary for it to make a decision. It encapsulates the actual decision-making logic, and returns an instance of the appropriate strategy object.

Answer (score 2):

I'd build a table with types which points to tables with codes, which in turn points to the implementing function to call for that type/code pair.

```c
lookup_type_table[type_low .. type_high] = { lookup_code_table_type_1, lookup_code_table_type_2, ...};
lookup_code_table_type_1[type_1_code_low .. type_1_code_high] = { type1_code1_func_pointer, ... };

int processPacket(int type, int code, paket_t data) {
  /* apply boundary checks on the lookup tables here! */
  return lookup_type_table[type][code](data);
}
```

The tables could be implemented as linked lists, or with some other fancier container implementation to make them more dynamic, if needed.

This might not be as object-oriented as some other patterns, but I'm coming from a C-background :)

Having the mappings in tables adds the possibility to generate them from some other DSL spec though, boosting your [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) stats...

Answer (score 0):

You can replace your switches with a dictionary of dictionaries which points to the actual methods or better classes to handle the packets. The first dictionary using type as index and the second using code as index.

But then you will have replaced the switch statements by the creating of the dictionaries, so in the end there isn't much difference.

You should have a look to the state pattern too, this kind of stuff is what its actually made for.