# Intelligent XML Traversal Using Java SAX

Tags: java, xml, design-patterns, sax

**Background:**

Recently, I have been tasked with parsing a large amount of data out of an HTML form and building it into a workable database table.  The HTML page in question was generated a long time ago, and the original source data has been lost to the ages.  Thus, I have decided to toss off a quick parser in Java to grab this data and format it appropriately.  SAX is to be leveraged, as I do not need to modify the hierarchy in any way and a single pass is all that is needed.  A very small sample of the HTML is included below:

```
<html>
 <table>
  <tr>
   <table>
    <tr>
     <td><div>District 1</div><td></tr>
    <tr>
     <td><div>Valid Code 1</div></td>
     <td><div>Valid Code 2</div></td>
     <td><div>Valid Code 3</div></td>
    </tr>
   </table>
  </tr>
ETC...
```

Obviously, there is more to the HTML than just what is outlined above but this should give an idea of the structure.

**Question:**

I am looking for an intelligent, extensible, self-documenting, and (if possible) fast / lean method of tracking my current location in the XML hierarchy using a SAX parser.  Since , using SAX, I have three discrete method calls that are only triggered for a single element, this state must be persistent and storable.  The obvious and easiest method of doing this would be a mountain of Boolean variables, but that is none of the prior four tenants that I have laid out.  I have also considered bitmasking to maintain a large number of flags, but that is hardly self-documenting or very extensible.  Finally, I have considered a Finite State Automata (or another similar derivative such as a Pushdown Automata) but those seem somewhat overkill for a one-off.

Perhaps I am over-thinking the problem for a one-off bit of code, bit I am always looking to expand my skill set for the times I have to write code that is not one-off.  Thank you in advance for your time and assistance.

**References:**

http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-sax-parser/

[Design pattern for a large nested switch statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6581382/design-pattern-for-a-large-nested-switch-statements)
(Not directly related to XML, but gives some ideas on designing with a large number of discrete conditions)

Comment: Can u say some rules like if u have a <td> then u can only have <div> in it ? I think u should say something like that, if u cant it doesn t seems to be doable I think. So if u can, there is a way in my mind:)

Comment: Sort of.  Notice that the main components are a table within a table.  Some tables they use <div> to surround the actual text, others they do not.  Some, I want to parse, others I do not.  The question is more geared to a good data structure for maintaining tree position and state.  If I really wanted to, this could all be boiled down to a comically large if-else chain (which would probably be the worst possible way to do it).  Ideally, I am hoping to get a solution that can be generalized to any arbitrary XML schema.

Comment: You can write a code -which u can use for analyse- to have all the xpath's in the html file. if u can have a structure like that, u can analyse which xpath s are data or group etc. Then u can parse it according to that map on runtime. I can not say that it will be fast but, it will be flexible I think

Answer (score 0):

I'd keep a stack of structures `{element, count}`, and for each `startElement()`, I'd increment parent structure's `count` and `push` a new element, and on `endElement()`, I'd `pop`.

That way, you would be able to keep an unique location in given document, and construct XPath like `/html/table/tr[23]/td[1]`. Or, faster but maybe more memory consumpting, you could copy the current stack.