# is it bad practice to use nesting switch statments in c++?

Tags: c++, nested, switch-statement

I've been working on a project in class and the code I have written so far works well. A big part of my code uses nested switch statements. While I'm going to turn it in the way it is now, I would like to know for future reference if nested switch statements are generally frowned upon.

Comment: Don't you want to show the code?

Comment: I think this is way too opinion based. For example, I absolutely hate switches and never use them. I use chains of if-else-if. That sends many people up a wall, as do their switches me. I can imagine nested switches being *especially* bad, but then I hated single switches. See the problem?

Comment: It really comes down to what you are doing. Sometimes it is the best option. Sometimes it is unnecessary. If you can avoid it it is often cheaper to not nest loops. However, increased complexity of the code itself is much worse so if a nested loop is the correct way to go, then great. However, try to make it recursive if you start getting more than 3 nested loops.

Comment: From the poing of view of OO: http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?SwitchStatementsSmell

Comment: Bad practice is to use more than one switch (or map, or if-else-if or whatever) on a given switch-value. E.g. if you have some input events - then have one switch per event-id per entire project - in subsequent points when decision should be taken based on event type  - you should use polymorphic operations.

Comment: Discussed in detail here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6581382/design-pattern-for-a-large-nested-switch-statements. Difficult to help you unless you post example code.

Comment: It's generally considered good style to put put one logical operation in one function. If you can represent the inner switch as a function it's probably a good idea to do so.

Comment: I've always found nested `switch` difficult to read. Fortunatly, stack overflow is always here to help us find alternatives: [How to branch/switch on multiple conditions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34414983/how-to-branch-switch-on-multiple-conditions).

Comment: Solution to switching on multiple conditions here. Would this be helpful? http://stackoverflow.com/q/34414983/2015579

Answer (score 4):

As you've probably noticed, because you asked, they're not exactly the easiest things to follow, so I would generally try to avoid them where possible.

This doesn't mean you can't do that kind of control flow - the trick being to split the cases out into their own functions. This lets someone read the top level switch, comprehend its branches and what happens (because you'll of course have given your functions good, descriptive names), and then they can examine each function in turn to understand the next level if they need to.

To avoid the cost of a function call which would previously have been unnecessary you can mark the functions `inline` to make the compiler effectively copy the body of the function to the call site.

It'd end up looking something like this incredibly genericised and incomplete skeleton:

```
int main() {
    int thing;
    char second_level_thing;

    // various code which produces thing and second_level_thing

    switch (thing) {
    case 0: do_zero_case(second_level_thing); break;
    case 1: do_one_case(); break;
    default: do_default_case(); break;
    }

    // the rest of main
}

inline void do_zero_case(char second_level_thing) {
   switch (second_level_thing) {
     case 'a': // 0 -> a branch code
     // etc...
   }
}

// etc...
```

Do *not* call your functions things like `do_zero_case`! Name them after what it actually *does*.

I would add that if multiple levels are inspecting the same value there's something very odd going on.

There are also alternative control flows available through use of OOP techniques (virtual method calls in a variety of forms), templates, higher-order functions and so forth. Sometimes a nice simple `switch` statement or two is exactly what you need though!

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, if and switch statements are more "costy" in terms of calculations for the proccessor, because you force the assembler to make new guesses (for what the next instructions will be) every time you jump from case to case. Try to use as less possible if your prime concern is algorithm efficiency.